# Replace specific pattern in a files with sed or replace

Tags: regex, linux, replace, sed

In my sitemap file i want to replace :(colon) with _ (underscore). But I don't want to replace other : in file such as timestamp.

my line

```
    <sitemap><loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap_2014-09-27_09:42:43_1.xml.gz</loc>
<lastmod>2014-09-27 09:42:43</lastmod></sitemap>
```

In this line "sitemap_2014-09-27_09:42:43_1.xml.gz" should become "sitemap_2014-09-27_09_42_43_1.xml.gz" but timestamp in  should not affect.

I am new to sed and patterns. Can someone provide sed or replace or any other linux command to replace this pattern in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this GNU sed command,

```
sed -r 's/([^ ])([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})/\1\2_\3_\4/g' file
```

Through basic sed,

```
sed 's/\([^ ]\)\([0-9]\{2\}\):\([0-9]\{2\}\):\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1\2_\3_\4/g' file
```

Comment: I tried first command its working ... but it is not changing file .. actually deleting everything from file

Comment: you need to add inline edit option `-i` to save the changes made.

Comment: `sed -ri 's/([^ ])([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})/\1\2_\3_\4/g' file`